# Who wrote the "Malbim" on the end of Devarim?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, pentateuch-chumash, ki-teitzei, deuteronomy

At the end of the Malbim's commentary to Devarim 22:21, there is a note which says:

> {מכאן עד סדר נצבים לא מצאנו באמתחת כתבי יד הגאון המחבר ז״ל וחבל על דאבדין. אמנם אנחנו קבצנו ובארנו על פי דרכו אשר הלך בו המחבר בבאורו התורה והמצוה עד כה:}

Who wrote the remainder of the commentary? And is it actually a faithful reflection of the Malbim, or is it an original work?

Comment: It is interesting to note that, as R' Copperman points out in his annotations on the Meshech Chachmah, that the Meshech Chachmah adopts the Malbim's style for the missing parts of Ki Seitzei in his own attempt to fill the gap. This despite the fact that his approach for the rest of his commentary was entirely different than that of the Malbim...

Answer (score 7):

It was authored by Rabbi Yosef Halevi Ya'avetz, and has been printed with the Malbim from the first printing. ([source](https://alhatorah.org/Commentators:R.%20Meir%20Leibush%20Weiser%20(Malbim)))

Comment: Thanks very much. That led me to https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53558&st=&pgnum=733&hilite=

Comment: @wfb wild stuff!

Comment: FWIW I went through Malbim Al Hatorah a few years ago and when I got to this point I found that you really can tell the difference between R' Yaavetz's style and the Malbim's. I doubt I would have figured out that it wasn't actually the Malbim, but after the fact it's totally not surprising.

Comment: +1 to רבות מחשבות. @wfb Interesting find although I didn't really understand his criticism towards R' Yaavetz. Is the problem that it's not clear enough that he appended his own commentary to the Malbim's commentary, or that he had the gall to think that he could 'complete' the Malbim's commentary?

Comment: @Harel13 Seems the author of the article is upset about both, plus the fact that he criticizes the Malbim's approach despite going on to "complete" his commentary